# Show that $\sum_{p\leq x}\log p(\frac 1{\log p}-\frac 1{\log x})=\int ^x_2\sum_{p\leq y}\frac{\log p}{(\log y)^2}\frac {dy}y$.

Tags: number-theory

Show that $$\sum_{p\leq x}\log p\left(\frac 1{\log p}-\frac 1{\log x}\right)=\int ^x_2\sum_{p\leq y}\frac{\log p}{(\log y)^2}\frac {\mathrm{d}y}y$$.

Using $$\int^x_p\frac 1{(\log y)^2}\frac{dy}y=\frac 1{\log p}-\frac 1{\log x},$$ we get $$\sum_{p\leq x}\log p\left(\frac 1{\log p}-\frac 1{\log x}\right)=\sum _{p\leq x}\int^x_p\frac{\log p}{(\log y)^2}\frac {dy}{y}=^? \int ^x_2\sum_{p\leq y}\frac{\log p}{(\log y)^2}\frac {dy}y$$. The last equality is not clear to me. If I plug in some number to $x$, I get the inequality. Could someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: "$p \le x$" does not adequately define the values of $p$ to be summed over. Apparently $p$ is integer. And obviously it must have some lower limit that explains the $2$. Please give the full conditions in the problem,

Comment: I'm sorry; p is prime number!